# is there a better way to test n functions with reduce? [JS]

Tags: javascript, function, testing, ecmascript-6, reduce

I made a simple function to test (invoke) an 'n' number of  arguments (functions) and return result as array, but I'm not sure if that is a right way to use reduce (check commented line below).

```js
const sucess = () => true;
const failed = () => false;


const tester = (...args) => {
 return [...args].reduce((acc,currentValue) => { 
    if(typeof acc === 'function') // this is right?
        return [acc(),currentValue()]
    return [...acc,currentValue()]
  });
}

console.log(tester(sucess,failed,failed,sucess));
```

what do you

Comment: I think that you should use `map` instead of `reduce`.

Comment: Never use `reduce` without the second argument, the initial accumulator value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to account for the first iteration where `acc` will be the first element of the array.

Fortunately `reduce` already has a way to account for this. Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the last argument is the `initialValue` that `acc` will start as. Only when no `initialValue` is given will `acc` ever be a function. In your case you can pass in an empty array `[]` like this:

```js
const sucess = () => true;
const failed = () => false;


const tester = (...args) => {
  return [...args].reduce((acc,currentValue) => ([...acc,currentValue()]), []);
}

console.log(tester(sucess,failed,failed,sucess));
```

This makes the logic very simple as you're guaranteed that `acc` is always an array and nothing else.

As an aside, as pointed out in the comments, what you're doing is transforming an array of some values with a mapping into an array of other values. This is the exact use case of `Array.map()`. The above can be accomplished more concisely like this:

```js
const sucess = () => true;
const failed = () => false;


const tester = (...args) => args.map(fn => fn());

console.log(tester(sucess,failed,failed,sucess));
```

Comment: "This makes the logic very simple as you're guaranteed that acc is always an array and nothing else."  that's all.

Nice answer, sorry for the late response.  Can you see the edit? thanks !

Comment: @elaineee I don't see any relation between the code in the edit and the original question. I suggest posting a new question, and if you think this question provides relevant context, insert a link to it when posting the new one.